# Mock method call inside class constructor with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Assume the following class

```
class Car {
  constructor() {
    this.startEngine()
  }

  startEngine = () => {
    console.log('BRRRM!')
  }
}
```

How do I mock `startEngine` so I can test if it was called in the constructor?

I somewhere read that I could access `startEngine` by `Car.prototype.startEngine`, but this does not seem to be the case as (in my case) Webpack hides the method in the `Car` function and are only accessible after instantiation (maybe because I defined it as an arrow function).

Comment: Deleting my answer as I noticed you are using an arrow function. Taking a look at this issue might help you : https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1136

Comment: Btw, It seems to me that a call to a specific method inside a constructor is a detail implementation. What I'd test here is simply if `BRRRM!` has been logged in the console after my object creation. It doesn't matter if it calls foo() or bar() to do it. I'd be curious to know if there is an answer to your question though